# Android HttpClient Post Request - Header Authentication

Tags: android, https, httpclient, http-post

So I'm trying to login to a asp.NET server over HTTPS via Android HttpClient Post.

When the POST request is executed, it will return one of two possibilities:

-An error login page (with Status Code 200)
-Successful Login default screen (with status code 302 -- theres a 302 redirect to the successful default page).

Sometimes it takes a while to load because I believe it is trying to read the whole content of the page, when all I truly need is the Status Code.

Here's my code:

```
response = client.execute(post,localContext);    

           name.post(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                name.setText("Http Code: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
           }
```

Is there anyway to make it only request/return the header tags so the user doesn't have to wait while it reads the entire page?

Also, it seems that even if I am using a correct user/pass, it returns 200, NEVER a 302.  I can post the source for that too, but what could be the problem? Could it be something HTTPS vs HTTP?

Thanks!:)